# Возникает ошибка sending message to a Handler on a dead thread

Tags: android, android-service, listener, locationmanager

Есть сервис унаследованный от `IntentService` и реализующий `LocationListener`.

Выглядит так:

```
public class LocationSenderService extends IntentService implements 

    LocationListener {

        @Inject
        ApiService mApiService;
        @Inject
        SPreferenceManager mSPreferenceManager;

        private LocationManager mLocationManager;

        public LocationSenderService() {
            super(LocationSenderService.class.getSimpleName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            MyApp.getAppComponent().inject(this);

            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable final Intent intent) {
            Timber.i("on handle intent");
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Timber.i("permissions not granted: %s, %s", Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

                stopSelf();
            }

            Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (location != null) {
                Timber.i("provider %s selected!", provider);

                onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, AppPrefs.LOCATION_INTERVAL, 1, this); //<<< Подписались
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() +
                    mSPreferenceManager.getPrefDeviceOffsetServer();

            Timber.i("onLocationChanged. location: %f - %f\ntime: %d",
                    location.getLongitude(),
                    location.getLatitude(),
                    timestamp);

            sendData(location.getLongitude(),
                    location.getLatitude(),
                    timestamp);
        }

        private void sendData(final double longitude, final double latitude, long timestamp) {
            CurrentLocationRequestData data = new CurrentLocationRequestData(longitude,
                                                                        latitude,
                                                                        timestamp);

            Timber.i("post current location...\n%s", data.toString());
            try {
                Response<CurrentLocationResponse> response
                        = mApiService.postSyncCurrentLocation(data, mSPreferenceManager.getPrefToken());

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Timber.i("... post is successful");

                    checkParameters(response.body().getParameters());
                } else {
                    Timber.i("... post NOT successful. code: %d", response.code());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Timber.e(e, "...error with sending current location");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this); //<<<Отписались
            stopSelf();
        }


        private void checkParameters(SendParameters parameters) {
            //...
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(final String s, final int i, final Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(final String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(final String s) {

        }
    }
```

После отписки ожидалось что и прекратит работу `LocationManager` рассылающий изменения подписчиков, но этого не происходит, так как каждые LOCATION_INTERVAL в лог попадает следующее сообщение:

```
W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1) {293ea6} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1) {293ea6} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                                                                    at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:543)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:507)
                                                                    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.onLocationChanged(LocationManager.java:248)
                                                                    at android.location.ILocationListener$Stub.onTransact(ILocationListener.java:58)
                                                                    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

Если я верно понял android продолжает рассылать сообщения, но тред в котором происходит его обработка уже мертв. По идее сервис уже к этому моменту должен быть отписан и действительно мертв.

Вопрос - что я делаю не так и какие могут быть последствия игнорирования данной проблемы?

Comment: Наследуйтесь от Service, а не от IntentService. Логику onHandleIntent перенесите в onStartCommand. Поток в IntentService завершается при завершении onHandleIntent, не дожидаясь вашей отписки.

Comment: @YuraIvanov но разве поток service не выполняется полностью в maitThread? Мне бы не хотелось в ui потоке выполнять вообще какую либо работу не связанную с ui

Comment: Верно. Service работает в главном потоке. И да, mApiService.postSyncCurrentLocation надо заменить на асинхронный вызов - retrofit выполнит запрос в отдельном потоке (call.enqueue).

Comment: Есть альтернативный вариант получения координат http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446569/how-to-receive-location-updates-without-using-a-service/6446582 intent'ом можно вызывать IntentService непосредственно для отправки координат. В любом случае ваш подход убивает IntentService по окончании onHandleIntent.

Comment: @YuraIvanov спасибо за совет, я так и сделал первым делом - сделал запрос асинхронным. Так же от проблемы избавился с минимальными потерями, запустив "прослушивание" с параметром getMainLooper который отправляет сообщение в mainThread минимизировава код выполняемый в ui потоке. Но все равно это как то так себе решение...

Comment: @YuraIvanov возможно альтернативный подход рабочий, проверю